# Fill array with random integer with a maximum number of sightings

Tags: java, arrays

I need help filling an array with specifics conditions.

I have an 2D array called `array` with size `[2][4]` and i need to fill it with `1` or `2` using a random int generator, i have done that, but not checking the limit of 1 or 2. The instructions are this: Fill an int 2d array with 1 or 2 checking that you can only have 4 sightings of 1, or 4 sightings of 2.

This would be an empty array example:

> 0  0   0   0
>   0  0   0   0

And this is an example of a terminated procedure:

> 1  1   2   2
>   2  1   2   1

PS: i don't want the above array exactly, just something like that.

Here's my code:

```
public static void generatePositions()
{
    int fbuenos = 0; //counts how many 2 there is
    int fmalos = 0; //counts how many 1 there is
    for (int x = 0; x <= 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y <= 4; y++)
        {
            int r = randInt(1, 2); //this is a method that return a random int
            pos[x][y] = r; //this gives value to the array slot
            //how and where do it put the conditions, that's my doubt
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Paste your written code above

Answer (score 0):

You could treat each instance of the random element as its own entity. If you do that, then you could use a more advanced data structure--like Vector--to help you along.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Vector<Integer> numbers = new Vector<>();
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(2);
    Integer[][] randomInts = new Integer[2][4];
    Random rng = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            int ix = rng.nextInt(numbers.size());
            Integer toInsert = numbers.remove(ix);
            randomInts[i][j] = toInsert;
        }
    }

    for (Integer[] subArray : randomInts) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subArray));
    }
 }
```

In effect, `numbers` is like a deck of cards. You initialize the deck with "cards" and "deal" them to the output array one at a time, randomly. You can't deal a card that isn't in the deck, so if there are only four 1s and four 2s, the output would have only four of each.

Answer (score 0):

I like this kind of problem. As I understand it, you can't just generate random numbers. Instead, in the case of a 2v4 for values 1 and 2, you have to make a set or list of 4 1's and 4 2's, and then randomly pull out those values. That way you can guarantee that you get 4 of each, even with randomness.

I've created a class that takes three arguments. The first argument is the width of the result array. The second argument is the height of the result array, and the third argument is the top of the range you will work with.

```
public class RandomFromPool {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Integer xVal = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    Integer yVal = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    Integer maxRandomNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    RandomFromPool rfp = new RandomFromPool(yVal, xVal, maxRandomNumber);
    rfp.generateRandom();
}

private int[][] results;
private Integer maxRandomNumber;

public RandomFromPool(Integer maxY, Integer maxX, Integer maxRandomNumber)
{
    results = new int[maxX][maxY];
    this.maxRandomNumber = maxRandomNumber;
}

private void generateRandom() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    //figure out how many of each possible value we want
    int neededTotal = results.length * results[0].length;
    int totalToGeneratePerVal = neededTotal % maxRandomNumber == 0? neededTotal / maxRandomNumber : neededTotal / maxRandomNumber + 1;
    //generate even number of all values
    List<Integer> generatedValues = new ArrayList<>(neededTotal);
    for(int i = 1; i <= maxRandomNumber; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < totalToGeneratePerVal; j++)
        {
            generatedValues.add(i);
        }
    }
    //grab randomly from the generated values - remove makes sure we only grab each item once
    for(int i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < results[0].length; j++)
        {
            results[i][j] = generatedValues.remove(rand.nextInt(generatedValues.size()));
        }
    }
    //print out the results
    for(int i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results[i]));
    }
}
```

An input of 2 4 2 generated these results (I ran it three times)

```
[2, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
and
[1, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 2, 1]
and 
[1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
```

and an input of 3 3 3 generated:

```
[1, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 2]
and
[1, 1, 2]
[3, 3, 1]
[2, 2, 3]
```

Comment: if you're doing this for a school project, I strongly suggest not just copy-pasting, but attempting to transfer it by hand. I found that I learned better when I did this, even though it seemed like busy work.

Comment: I don't doubt this works, but just way too complicated. I updated my question with my code, i just need the rigth conditions, but cannot think correctly, don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Well made it after going step by step, here is the code for anyone who wants to see it:

```
public static void generatePositions()
{
    int fbuenos = 0;
    int fmalos = 0;
    //generar fantasmas enemigos
    for (int x = 0; x <= 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y <= 4; y++)
        {
            int r = randInt(1, 2);

            if (r == 1)
            {
                if (fmalos >= 4)
                {
                    pos[x][y] = 2;
                    fbuenos++;
                }
                else{
                    pos[x][y] = 1;
                    fmalos++;
                }
            }
            else{
                if (fbuenos >= 4)
                {
                    pos[x][y] = 1;
                    fmalos++;
                }
                else{
                    pos[x][y] = 2;
                    fbuenos++;
                }
            }

        }


    }
}
```